# How to identify element with the same name in coded UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to identify an element for codedUI test using the same element. How do we do it. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public HtmlControl child()
{
 HtmlControl parent = new HtmlControl(browser);
 parent.SearchProperties["id"] = "[my id]";

 HtmlControl child = new HtmlControl(parent);
 child.SearchProperties["innerText"] = "[the inner text]";
 return child;
}
```

Comment: @user2852847 Saying "It did not work" tells us nothing useful. Please edit the original question to explain the problem in more detail.